# CakePHP how to change __() language in the same request

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization, gettext

I'm on CakePHP 2.6.x

My app is localized in French and English. English is the default.

My translation files currently look like this:

```
/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
/app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

In my views, I normally can show localized text for the current language like this:

```
echo __("Foo");
```

However, in a few situations I need to override the current language and return a translation for a specific language. My understanding is [__d()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#global-functions) is meant for exactly this. However, the following does NOT work for me:

```
echo __d("fra", "Foo");
```

[Correction: `__d` is NOT meant for this.]

This seems to always return the translation of the current language. Basically acting just link `__()`.

After a lot of trial-and-error I renamed the French .PO file...

```
/app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/fra.po
```

...and then `__d("fra", "Foo");` *DOES* work as expected. But then `__()` *DOESN'T* work anymore. After I change the file name, all instances of `__()` return text in the default language.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get BOTH `__d()` and `_()` to work at the same time? Or another way of asking the same question: How can I change the language used by `__()` within the same request?

**Update**

My first instinct was to try something like what Lars suggests below. But for some reason it doesn't work. I'm doing the following in an email view:

```
    Configure::write("Config.language", "fra");
    $this->log(Configure::read("Config.language")); //'fra'
    $this->log( __("yes") ); //'yes'
```

Notice that the Config  language is correctly set. But `__()` ignores it and echos the current language anyway. (Btw I checked and yes/oui is in the PO file)

Comment: Possible quick workaround: make a symbolic link in your LC_MESSAGES directory from default.po to fra.po e.g. `ln -s default.po fra.po`.

Comment: @marian0 Hmm. That hack might work but I suspect it will cause me suffering in the future :-) . I really need to figure out what I'm doing wrong to cause Cake's l10n not to work as expected.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. The `__d` function is not used to overwrite the language, it's used to pick another language file ***within*** the language that is currently set.

Comment: @silkfire Huh. So `__d` IS acting as expected? Is there a different function for what I want to do?

Comment: No i'm afraid not. You can switch the language prior to executing `__` and then switch back, I guess. What is it that you want to achieve as you've chosen to go this route?

Comment: @silkfire I need to send some emails and the text needs to be localized for the recipient (not the current language of the sender). I did some experiments adding `Configure::write('Config.language', $lg )` but it didn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're wrong `__d() stands` for *domain*, to separate translations into different domains (and files). For example "backend" and "frontend". It is explained pretty early in the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#internationalizing-your-application you should read the whole sectione before starting to work on a i18n app.

Comment: @burzum who is wrong? I think we established that `__d()` is not for overtly choosing a language. Is that what you are saying? Any ideas about how to do it correctly?

Comment: @SDP Yeah then try Lars' solution below as it does exactly what I was describing above :)

Comment: In case the configured language is not being used despite the correct files being available, check whether a language is set in the session (`CakeSession::read('Config.language')`), this is used over `Configure`, and make sure that you've cleared the cache `tmp/cache/persistent` after making changes to your translations.

Comment: @ndm The session is also set. That explains why it isn't working. But how can I override the session language on the current request? $this->Session->write() will only effect the next one right?

Comment: It will also affect the current request, internally `I18N::translate()` reads the value every time it is being invoked. So you could switch it back and forth just like `Configure`. In case you need to do this more often, you should look into wrapping the direct `I18N::translate()` usage in a custom function and avoid the session/config extra steps. ps, I'm lazy today, so you might want to add the solution as an answer yourself ;)

Comment: @ndm Gotcha. I'm on it. Is there a best practice regarding the use of Session vs Configure for localization setting? My current implementation sets both as I see many other do too, but it's always struck me as a bit odd / confusing.

Comment: The best practice would be to use whatever is appropriate to solve the problem, ie if for example  3rd party code sets the session, or if you need to persist the language from a value that is not available on every single request, use the session, otherwise you can stick with configure.

Comment: @SDP yes, I'm saying that __d() is not thought for what you think it is thought for. It is for *domains*, there is even *context*. __d() is *not* for switching the language on the fly. Do some research on how translations are done the right way. Read the gettext documentation for example.

Comment: @ndm I posted an answer with a little utility that seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @ndm's suggestion, I wrote a little utility for "toggling" the language mid-request.

Here's how I use it:

```
App::uses('L10nTool', 'Lib');
$L10n = new L10nTool();
$L10n->startToggleLg("fra");
...
//Bonjour, mon ami
...
$L10n->stopToggleLg();//Back to initial language
```

Later I might add another method, similar Lars's answer, for doing one quick string in a single method. But right now I'm doing some email logic in the "toggled" language, so it's easier for me to do it this way.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class L10nTool {

    public $start_lg;
    public $use_session = FALSE;

    public function startToggleLg($lg) {

        if (CakeSession::check("Config.language")) { 
            $this->start_lg = CakeSession::read("Config.language");
            $this->use_session = TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->start_lg = Configure::read("Config.language");
        }

        if ( $this->use_session ) {
            CakeSession::write("Config.language", $lg);
        } else {
            Configure::write("Config.language", $lg);
        }

    }

    public function stopToggleLg($lg = NULL) {

        $lg = ($lg) ? $lg : $this->start_lg;

        if ( $this->use_session ) {
            CakeSession::write("Config.language", $lg);
        } else {
            Configure::write("Config.language", $lg);
        }        

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to change the set language prior the call and change it back later:

```
$before = Configure::read('Config.language');
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
echo __('Your String');
Configure::write('Config.language', $before);
```

You could even put that into a function:

```
function __lang($string, $language) {
    $before = Configure::read('Config.language');
    Configure::write('Config.language', $language);
    echo __($string);
    Configure::write('Config.language', $before);
}
```

### Edit

As mdm explained in the comments, that is basically what the [I18N::translate](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-I18n.html#_translate) function does.

If this (and my function) does not work, I would guess that there is something wrong with your translation files. Have you tried switching to the target language globally? Does that print the correct string?

To circumvent all configuration and session values, you could simply rely on the I18N::translate function:

```
function __lang($string, $language) {
    echo I18N::translate($string, null, null, I18n::LC_MESSAGES, null, $language);
}
```

Comment: Maybe also explain the direct usage of `I18N::translate()` (here you can explicitly pass a language that is used over the configured one) and `I18N::insertArgs()`, just like the `_*()` methods do internally.

Comment: @ndm That sounds like EXACTLY what I need. No?

Comment: @Lars Your solution is something I tried but cannot get to work. I'm updating my question to show the problem...

Comment: @ndm I did not know they existed ;)

Comment: I edited my answer to use the I18N class directly, this should ignore all present language settings.